# Cant get rounded corners on my image in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, rounded-corners

I use visual composer in Wordpress and both when I make the image here rounded, either with Visual composer or directly with CSS it still does not become rounded in the corners.

Link: http://hope.ly/13Aaqw8

Does anyone have any ideas ? Suggestions ?

Comment: please explain what image you are talking about + include the [relevant code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself

Answer (score 1):

You can set border radius on the parent wrapper:

```
.wpb_column > .wpb_wrapper *:last-child {
   margin-bottom: 0;
   -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
   -moz-border-radius: 25px;
   border-radius: 25px;
}
```

But this will depend on the cropping of the image inside this wrapper.

It looks ok to me when I edited it directly in the chrome inspector. but you should post your own code really to see what you have tried.